# UUID from String not working in app, but works in Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, uuid, guid, swift-playground

Simple but crazy question

I have a line of code, that I put real simple in my AppDelegate, before anything loads:

```
let test = UUID(uuidString: "d0f98621-a577-4b56-987b-6519bdb61c30")
```

The value returns nil

If I then move to a playground, and take the exact same line of code:

```
let test = UUID(uuidString: "d0f98621-a577-4b56-987b-6519bdb61c30")
```

It tells me this is a valid UUID and writes the variable out in the margin on the right in the playground.

How can I even begin to troubleshoot something like this? I don't recall overriding or subclassing UUID somehow and making a new uuidString implementation.

Thanks so much!

[image: Playground]

[image: The tooltip says it is nil]

[image: String is working!]

Comment: "How can I even begin to troubleshoot something like this?"  You are returning an optional value, right?

Comment: What version of a UUID is it with lower-case letters?

Comment: I strongly suspect that this line of code is not the exact line of code you have put in your AppDelegate, or that this line of code does not actually run in your AppDelegate. The way you troubleshoot this is to keep simplifying your problem until it goes away. Create a trivial app that only has an AppDelegate, and this one line of code, and prints the result. Move up from there, and down from your actual program until they are equivalent. (But I'm betting this isn't the line you've provided, character-for-character, followed by `print(test)`.) If it is, post a full example.

Comment: So @ElTomato I was using the tooltip / hover over to see if it was nil. Printing the value in debug (with "p") didn't yield anything but doing the above it returned a real string after I unwrapped it. Why, though, did it say the value was nil for an optional?

Comment: Use uppercase letters.